# REST service test with JUnit using Java EE annotations

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, junit, mockito

I use Java EE 6 running on GlassFish and Jersey.

How can I mock a request to this resource with some custom headers, and some other request details?

```
@Stateless
@Path("/user")
public class Resources {

@Contex
private HttpServletRequest request;
....

@GET
@Path("/settings")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public AccountSettings accountSettings() {
    //check custom headers and request content do some stuff
    return accountSettings;
}

    ....
}
```

And this is my java code, but I get null pointer exception on **res.accountSettings() because request is still null.**

```
@Mock
HttpServletRequest request= Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);

@Test
public void testResources() {
    when(request.getHeader(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)).thenReturn("Basic wedwd");
    Resources res=new Resources();
    AccountSettings response=res.accountSettings();

}
```

Instead of create with **new** keyword, When I use this then I also get the resources null.

```
 @Inject Resources resources
```

Comment: How is `Resources` and `request` connected?

Comment: @Anders R. Bystrup  thast the problem I couldnt connect them, I tried to inject Resources to my test class instead of create by "new" but I still get null

Comment: You have done most of the work.  You just now need to do the injection - i.e. your test method needs to set the request attribute of the Resources class.  This simulates the actual runtime behavior.  Does the Resources class not have a setter for the request?  If it does, simply call it in your test method.

Comment: @EJK I use Contex HttpServletRequest request; as you can see in the code, but injection in Test class did not work I get null

Comment: @Spring - The injection is done by your JAX-RS provider.  In your unit test, that provider/container is not present.  Your test is simply a class running in JUnit.  Thus it is on you, the test author, to simulate the behavior of the actual runtime container ---> So you must call a setter for the request.

Comment: @EJK normally I dont use a setter getter in Resources, just created one to just for junit testing and it worked, I wonder if there is any other way to do it, without adding setter getters to my classes

Comment: @Spring - According to the JAX-RS spec, http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html, the Context annotation injects data into a class field.  It may do so using reflection or some other technique.  For you to simulate this, using a setter is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do as follow with an @InjectMocks annotation, it outside any JAXRS context or CDI injection stuff, it treated as a regular java class.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ResourcesTest {

    @Mock HttpServletRequest request;

    @InjectMocks Resources res;

    @Test
    public void testResources() {
        // given
        when(request.getHeader(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)).thenReturn("Basic wedwd");

        // when
        AccountSettings response = res.accountSettings();

        // then
        ...
    }
}
```